# Using HTML entities in input name attribute

Tags: php, html, html-entities

Because I am lazy, I want to name a bunch of inputs using their scientific units so that I can later run a foreach() loop and use the array key as the parameter label.

```
<?php print_r($_POST) ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="param[&deg;]" value="<?php $_POST['param']['&deg;'] ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

But alas, `&deg;` changes to `°` automatically, which to me is unexpected behavior. Who is responsible for this change and is this part of some standard? Is there a way to ensure that the array key remains the same?

Comment: you have to use the entity for the & `name="param[&amp;deg;]"`

Comment: I could also use `$_POST['param']['°']`, but which is safer?

Comment: A unit symbol does not sound logical here. You do not read units, you read quantities, so if you wish to use scientific names for inputs, use unit symbols. This will avoid the problem described here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&deg;` notation is replaced by its defined meaning, the DEGREE SIGN “°”, by a web browser, or other HTML client, when parsing an HTML document. This is a defined and required process according to all HTML specifications.

If you want the literal string `&deg;` to appear in parsed HTML content, you need to write it e.g. as `&amp;deg;`. But that string is not a scientific unit; it is just an HTML notation that may be used when you cannot or do not wish to type “°” directly.